# Apple Magic Mouse on PC

Tags: windows-7

Anyone succeeded to use gestures on PC with windows 7? What I've done is extracted bootcamp of SL, run driver software, then add bluetooth device (magic mouse) and it basically works, with hard button clicks also the single finger scroll function works. But for example this one does not work

> Click
>
> Magic Mouse is an advanced point-and-click mouse that lets you
>   click and double-click anywhere on its
>   Multi-Touch surface.

Comment: This is no longer true - the magicpad supports click and double click by tapping the surface now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot tap or double-tap on its surface (as you do in a laptop trackpad). There are only hard clicks (left and right) and scrolling. I don't think apple supports two-finger swipe on windows (why would they, it's a competitive advantage to go and buy a MAC). The description states "click and double-click anywhere.." There is a threshold on where the clicking stops. I think it works up to 2/3 of the surface , the other 1/3 is for your palm, in order to hold the mouse. 
if you own a mac, there is a third party app that lets you add custom gestures to your magic mouse. For example I've added 3-finger swipe down for expose and 3-finger swipe-up for showing the desktop. I don't remember the name of the app, but a bit googling will help you.

Comment: the name is jitouch and it is awesome! I mainly use it to enable middle-clicking on the trackpad and a Magic Mouse. OSX only, though.

Comment: The one I am using is called "BetterTouchTool". Works great on Magic Mouse and Trackpad and it's FREE!